# Best way to manage multiple 12V inputs and outputs from Arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage, opto-isolator, level-shifting

For a bowling alley I am going to make a circuit using an Arduino Mega to turn on arrow lights(1-4 bulbs in each) given the bowling pin lights that are lit up at the moment on a masking unit. AMF no longer makes the board that originally did this internal to the pinspotter chassis. All of these lights are 67 bulbs(BA15S base, 12V). Here is a draw-up of the plug from the chassis that lights up the pin lights:
[image]

How these pin lights are wired is that the 12V(Pin 29) is wired in parallel to all of the lights and then to turn on that pin light, the chassis grounds out the specific pin(14-23) that the other end of the pin light is wired to:[image]

My question is, what is the best way to go about getting 5V inputs from these lights and then controlling 12V to power the arrow bulbs?

What I am thinking for the inputs is using opto-isolators. Here is an example of knowing when bowling pin 1(Pin 18 on the plug) is on/grounded:
[image]

For the outputs, there are 11 arrows in total for each lane. I was thinking of using relays, with the 12VDC(Pin 29) going to the common and then the NC and NO would go to the bulbs for each arrow, then going to the Ground on the plug(Pin 2).

Is there a better way about doing this? I looked at the patent for the board AMF used to make and it shown they used NOR Gates, optical couplers, a ROM/PROM for determining the arrow, and a decoder. I don't have much knowledge about ROMs or PROMs.

Edit: I am planning on using IRLZ44NPBF or STP16NF06L MOSFETs, will these be good enough for switching 12V at most around 1.2A(for the arrow which has 4 bulbs in it, the rest would have lower current)?

Comment: In your optoisolator drawing, the LED and resistor should be connected in parallel with the existing light - as drawn, the LED will not light.

Comment: Optocoupler should connect pin to ground, not to 5V, becouse arduino has integrated pull up, not pull down. If the current is not too high - ULN2003 can be used for open collector not isolated drive.

Comment: you drew the left end of the 1.2 k resistor and the right end of the  LED both connected to ground ... there is no voltage at the left end of the resistor that would push current through the resistor and the LED

Comment: @fifi_22, actually, a modern almost-zero-loss FET pack, not the antique power-wasting ULN2003A.

Comment: I created the diagram in a hurry so yes, the opto-isolator would be wired in parallel across the light and the 5v would be the ground pin. The lights would pull 133mA-590mA.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and put these corrections in. Otherwise people would have to hunt for comments and piece the actual question together.

Comment: Lights aren't inputs, so you're going to have to specify what actually are.  For the outputs you probably want low side transistor/FET drivers, perhaps if the current is workable the ULN200x or similar series.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can't modify anything inside of the chassis as it has a lifetime warranty, so I have to use pins 14-23 for the inputs. What's wrong with wiring the opto-isolator in parallel with each of the lights?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I really don't understand what you are trying to ask. The lights are going to be in parallel with opto-isolators for each ground which should be enough to power the opto-isolator to close the input on the Arduino side of the opto-isolator.

Comment: I added an additional question at the end of the post since I am going to be using MOSFET's for the outputs.